# Can a application be a WPF desktop application and also a WCF service?

Tags: wpf, wcf, web, service, desktop-application

I have a WPF desktop application. This application is required to expose certain functions for the external remote clients. Currently we have a socket protocol which we expose for the external clients. Can we instead (or also) use WCF to expose these functions as a service ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, you should have just tried it before asking here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosting WCF web service inside WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453590/hosting-wcf-web-service-inside-wpf-application)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll simply need to create and start a [ServiceHost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816211/3042204) for your WCF service.